# Java: check if arraylist is part of fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, arraylist, fibonacci

My assignment for school is to implement a method that checks if a given `ArrayList` is part of the Fibonacci sequence.

The array must not be empty and must be bigger than 3.

I understood that I have to check if one number of the array and the next one are part of the Fibonacci sequence, however I have a lot of trouble with it since you're supposed to accept the array if it's any part of the sequence and not just from the start.

e.g.: `0 1 1 2 3 5` will be accepted as well as `2 3 5 8 13 21`.

This is my code so far. I know it's very flawed but i really have no clue how to move on.

```
public class ArrayCheck {
 /**
 * Tests if the given array is a part of the Fibonacci sequence.
 *
 * @param arr array to be tested
 * @return true if the elements are part of the fibonacci sequence
 */
public boolean isFibonacci(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
    //check if array exists
    if(arr.size() == 0)
        return false;

    //check if array is bigger than 3
    if (arr.size() < 3)
        return false;

    //check for the startsequence of 0,1,1
    else if(arr.get(0) == 0 && arr.get(1) == 1 && arr.get(2) == 1)
        return true;

    //check every number in array
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        //check if i >= 2 is fib
        if(i >= 2) {
            int fibn = i;
            int nextfib = i + 1;

            int fibnew = (fibn - 1) + (fibn - 2);
            int fibnext = (nextfib - 1) + (nextfib - 2);

            if (arr.get(i) != fibnew && arr.get(i + 1) != fibnext)
                return false;
        }
        //check if the order is right
        if(arr.get(i) > arr.get(i+1))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have a few issues with your code. First of all, if you array is at least 3 items, you check if only the first three are the start of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
//check for the startsequence of 0,1,1
else if(arr.get(0)==0 && arr.get(1)==1 && arr.get(2)==1){
    return true;
}
```

This is bad, as this mean `0 1 1 5` which is not part of the sequence will return true.

What you need to do is split this into two tasks:

- Find the first relevant number in the sequence (i.e. if the array starts with `7`, you know this isn't a part of the sequence; alternatively, if it starts with `8`, you know you need to start checking from `8` onward).
- Once you've found the "start", simply check that the rest of the array follows the Fibonacci rule. you'll need to manually verify the first two items.

---

```
public boolean isFibonacci(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {

    if (arr.size() < 3){
        return false;
    }

    /** find if the first element is part of the sequence: **/

    int fib1 = 0;
    int fib2 = 1;

    while (fib1 < arr.get(0)) {
        int tmp = fib1 + fib2;
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = tmp;
    }

    if (fib1 != arr.get(0)) {
        // first element is not part of Fibonacci sequence
        return false;
    }

    if (fib2 != arr.get(1)) {
       // the first two elements are not part of the Fibonacci sequence
       return false;
    }

    /*** now simply verify that the rest of the elements uphold the rule:
         each element is the sum of the two previous ones: **/

    for(int i=2; i < arr.size(); i++) {

        // make sure there are no negatives in the array:
        if (arr.get(i) < 0)
           return false;

        if (arr.get(i) != (arr.get(i-1) + arr.get(i-2)))
           return false;

    }

    //everything checks out okay - return true:
    return true;
}
```

Comment: actually no need to check for negative numbers. The first negative value, if any exists in the array, is prepended by at least two positive numbers-- which makes sum constraint violated (no such two numbers > 0 that sum in < 0).

Comment: You're right. I was being overly cautious. Thank you :)

Comment: Did you test this implementation?

Comment: actually, after i implemented it, i ran some junit tests and it would not return true for actual fibonacci sequences, everything else worked. however, after changing this line
    `while (fib1 <= arr.get(0)) {
to while (fib1 < arr.get(0)) {`
i got no more errors

Comment: Because, as I "hinted"... it doesn't work. Particularly by the time the 1st `while` is done, `fib1 != arr.get(0)` is **always true**, and this result in an automatic return of `false`. Code is simply wrong.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, the first loop's condition should have been `fib1 < arr.get(0)` and not `<=`. My bad. Thanks Amit!

Comment: even edited, this code doesn't take into consideration a special case when a sequence starts by a "second" 1 in Fibo, e. g. `[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]`

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean isFib(final List<Integer> li) {
    //check if each int is the sum of the two prior ints
    for (int i = 2; i < li.size(); i++) {
        if (li.get(i) != li.get(i - 1) + li.get(i - 2)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //reverse the fibonacci sequence and check if we end up at the correct starting point (0, 1)
    int i1 = li.get(0);
    int i2 = li.get(1);

    while (i1 > 0) {
        final int tmp = i1;
        i1 = i2 - i1;
        i2 = tmp;
    }

    return i1 == 0 && i2 == 1;
}
```

Comment: no, because `2, 2, 4, 6` for example is not a part of the fibbonaci sequence.

Comment: Then you are accepting this one: [2 2 4 6 10] which is not part of fibonacci.

Comment: Fixed it, checks the first digit. Or not. The point was loop starting from index 2..

Comment: Is this a valid fibonacci? [0 5 5 10]

Comment: That would be taken care of by a guard if.

Comment: This only works for fibonacci sequances containing the head part

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a solution which abstracts Fibonacci sequence generator in a separate `Iterator<Integer>`, then uses it to check if provided list matches any part of the sequence.

Iterator is quite simple and straightforward:

```
public static class FiboIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { return true; }

    int i = -1, j = -1;   // previous two items of Fibo sequence

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        int k = (i < 0) ? (j < 0 ? 0 : 1) : (i + j);
        i = j;
        j = k;
        return k;
    }
}
```

Main checking method:

```
public static boolean isFibo(List<Integer> seq) {
    if (seq.size() < 3)
        return false;
    final Iterator<Integer> f = new FiboIterator();
    int start = seq.get(0), k;
    while ((k = f.next()) < start);         // roll Fibo to match the starting item in input
    if (start != k)                         // starting item doesn't match
        return false;
    if (start == 1 && seq.get(1) != 1)      // special case: [1, 2, ...]
        f.next(); 
    for (int i = 1; i < seq.size(); i++) {  // check if other items match
        if (seq.get(i) != f.next())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And finally a few unit tests:

```
@Test
public void testFibo() {
    assertTrue(isFibo(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 1, 2)));
    assertTrue(isFibo(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 5)));
    assertTrue(isFibo(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 8)));
    assertTrue(isFibo(Arrays.asList(5, 8, 13, 21, 34)));

    assertFalse(isFibo(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 0)));
    assertFalse(isFibo(Arrays.asList(1, 0, 1)));
    assertFalse(isFibo(Arrays.asList(5, 5, 10, 15)));
}
```