# Check if arraylist is part of fibonacci sequence c#

Tags: c#, list, fibonacci

I found on this link similar solution [Java: check if arraylist is part of fibonacci sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102143/java-check-if-arraylist-is-part-of-fibonacci-sequence), but I want that in c#. I tray to convert that in c# but it doesn't work. Can someone help me and tell me where I'm wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 };
        Console.WriteLine(isFibonacci(list));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 public static bool isFibonacci(List<int> arr)
    {

        if (arr.Count() < 3)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int fib1 = 0;
        int fib2 = 1;

        while (fib1 < arr.IndexOf(0))
        {
            int tmp = fib1 + fib2;
            fib1 = fib2;
            fib2 = tmp;
        }

        if (fib1 != arr.IndexOf(0))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (fib2 != arr.IndexOf(1))
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < arr.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (arr.IndexOf(i) < 0)
                return false;

            // I think that problem is in this part of code
            if (arr.IndexOf(i) != (arr.IndexOf(i - 1) + arr.IndexOf(i - 2))) 
                return false;
        }
        return true;
     }
```

Comment: The code seems correct at first sight. What does "doesn't work" exactly mean?

Comment: Can you say which value your code is returning false for ?

Comment: I put a comment in code where I think is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List.IndexOf method returns the index of the element specified as arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Didn't you rather want to get the element at the specified index, which would be arr[i]?

Updated source code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 };
        Console.WriteLine(isFibonacci(list));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static bool isFibonacci(List<int> arr)
    {

        if (arr.Count() < 3)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int fib1 = 0;
        int fib2 = 1;

        while (fib1 < arr[0])
        {
            int tmp = fib1 + fib2;
            fib1 = fib2;
            fib2 = tmp;
        }

        if (fib1 != arr[0])
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (fib2 != arr[1])
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < arr.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] < 0)
                return false;

            // I think that problem is in this part of code
            if (arr[i] != (arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: He coud use `[]` instead of `IndexOf()`, but how would that solve the problem?

Comment: In c# an indexer `[]` and `IndexOf()` methods are not equivalent. The equivalent of an indexer the `ElementAt()` is.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right! I read this `IndexOf` so often in this code but it did not hit me. So actually my answer is probably totally wrong.

Comment: @rené-vogt: why did you down vote my answer? The problem wasn't with the chosen collection type, `List<T>` can hold duplicates just fine; the problem was with the wrong usage of the `IndexOf()` method. Please remove your down vote.

Comment: as I said before, I was blind and wrong and thought that your answer would not solve the problem at all. After you showed me my mistake, I took away the downvote again and upvoted your answer and told OP to accept your answer, as he did now. I apologize for the incorrect down vote.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to the question. I just thought it would be fun to do this in LINQ.

You can do it this way:

```
public static bool isFibonacci(List<int> arr)
{
    return
        arr
            .Zip(
                arr.Skip(1),
                (x0, x1) => new { x0, x1 })
            .Zip(
                arr.Skip(2),
                (x01, x2) => x01.x0 + x01.x1 - x2 == 0)
            .All(x => x);
}
```

Or this with the Interactive Extensions (NuGet "Ix-Main"):

```
public static bool isFibonacci(List<int> arr)
{
    return arr.Buffer(3, 1).Where(x => x.Count == 3).All(x => x[0] + x[1] == x[2]);
}
```